# Prevent googlebot from calling ajax methods

Tags: .net, ajax, googlebot, .net-3.5

Googlebot keeps trying to call ajax methods on my website.
For example: default.aspx/GetStuffWithAjax

The problem is that this method should be impossible for google to call since im checking with javascript if the querystring has id=xxxx before calling it. There is no link anywhere with this querystring that google could follow.

Is is possible that the bot scans for PageMethods.GetStuffWithAjax in my html code and then just tries to call the ajax method? And how could I prevent this.. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `Disallow: /GetStuffWithAjax` as a line in your `robots.txt` file at your domain's root.

Comment: Just a little note on this. I had to put /page.aspx/GetStuffWithAjax in robots.txt. Wouldnt work with just the method name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `robots.txt` to tell Google (and other good bots) not to go there. Check here:

- http://www.robotstxt.org/